# Loading external library in Laravel-4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to load the [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) in my `Laravel-4` project. However, I can't get it to find the class. I am getting this error:

```
Class 'Libraries\SimpleHtmlDom\simple_html_dom_node' not found
```

I've put `simple_html_dom.php` in `app\libraries` and

```
namespace Libraries\SimpleHtmlDom;
```

in the top of `simple_html_dom.php`.

In `global.php` I've added the `libraries` folder:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/libraries',

));
```

And finally, in my controller, I am trying to instantiate it:

```
$parser = new Libraries\SimpleHtmlDom\simple_html_dom_node;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Specific to your use case

To (hopefully) solve your problem without changing your current structure, you may just need to run:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

Or you may need to add an autoloaded section in `composer.json` along with the others:

```
    "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                    "app/commands",
                    "app/controllers",
                    "app/models",
                    "app/database/migrations",
                    "app/database/seeds",
                    "app/tests/TestCase.php",
                    "app/libraries"
            ]
    },
```

And then run `composer dump-autoload` again.

## Packagist (better?) Solution

It looks like there's a Composer package you could be using instead:  https://packagist.org/packages/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser

This makes adding it to your project easier:

**A.** Add dependency to `composer.json` (either via this CLI call or by adding manually to your composer.json file):

```
# Run this command:
$ composer require "sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser": "1.5.0.*@dev"
```

**B.** [Use new package](https://github.com/sunra/php-simple-html-dom-parser) in your code

```
$dom = HtmlDomParser::file_get_html( $file_name );
```